# gettext(i18n) in process running as root/system process

Tags: c#, locale, gettext

It's not possible to setlocale of a process running as root, how can I use gettext to obtain localized strings (the locale is not auto detected, nor can I force it to a particular value using setlocale) in such a process. Is there any workaround?

Edit -> Adding the code, I used for testing the issue. I force changed the environment variables - LC_ALL, LANGUAGE, LANG to fr_FR.UTF8. I set the locale to fr_FR.UTF8 explicitly too. All the putenv calls returned 0 and the setlocale call returned "C".

```
 int err = putenv("LC_ALL=fr_FR.UTF8");
 err = putenv("LANG=fr_FR.UTF8");
 err = putenv("LANGUAGE=fr_FR.UTF8");
 char *loc = setlocale(LC_ALL, "fr_FR.UTF8");
 bindtextdomain("default", "locale");
 textdomain("default");
 char *text = gettext("hello");
```

The same code snippet works if I try it in a user process. The exe of both the processes are in same directory, which contains directory locale\fr\LC_MESSAGES\default.mo

Can we change the locale of a process which is running as system process and not user?

Comment: How are you testing this? What platform?

Comment: Windows - System process

Comment: I'm calling char * loc = setlocale(de_DE.UTF8) in a system process and user process. In system process it returns loc as NULL and in user process it returns it fine as "de_DE.UTF8"

Comment: The `setlocale()` manpage on my system shows `setlocale()` takes two arguments; one for the locale, one for the category to modify. Can you post a short reproducer program?

Comment: Added code and more information to explain my question. Sorry, I missed the category in setlocale in my comment above